# Retrieve data from Table A based on Table B using Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I have two tables: requestgenerals and requestinformations. 
The relationship between the 2 tables is:

- requestinformations `belongsTo` requestgenerals
- requestgenerals `hasMany` requestinformation.

Below are the tables:
requestgenerals table
[image]

and
requestinformations table
[image]

I tried the following: `$requestgenerals = Requestgeneral::without('requestinformation')->get();` but I still get all the rows from the requestgenerals table instead of just two.Please assist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use this:

```
$requestgenerals = Requestgeneral::doesntHave('requestinformations')->get();
```

if you want to get all records that don't have related record in second table. Take a look at [Eloquent documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence).

Answer (score 1):

Use `doesntHave` for get data doestnt have `requestinformations`

```
$requestgenerals = Requestgeneral::doesntHave('requestinformations')->get();
```

For refernce refer this link

[Example](https://laraveldaily.com/eloquent-doesnthave-get-rows-children/)